# Picking icon in font for polybar

Tags: fonts, desktop-environment, icons, toolbar, lemonbar

I always am in trouble with picking icons in my fonts to build my polybar.

I tried with some gnome tools like gnome-characters or gnome-font-viewer but I can't figure out how to display icons (instead of alphanumerical only) and I end up trying printf some random unicode to copy past into my text editor.

Do you guys have a good tool (cli or gui, it doesn't mater) to list available icons in given fonts or methodologies to find it for example on web databases ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: Ok I found a way !
Use gucharmap, select your font and go to 'private use area'

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question and accept it.